# Algorithm similar to the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given a prime number $p$, and an initial number $1<a<p$, what would be the upper bound on the iteration number of the following algorithm?

(1) if $a=1$ then stop

(2) else replace $a$ by $p - a\lfloor\frac{p}{a}\rfloor$, i.e. the remainder when $p$ is divided by $a$.

I suspect that the number of iterations can be bounded by $O(\log p)$ for any given $a$. I have checekd all primes $p\leq 100000$, and the maximum number of iterations was something like 43.

I have proved the bound $O(\sqrt p)$, by making the observation that $\lfloor \frac{p}{a}\rfloor$ strictly increases per operation.

Would there by any better bound?

Comment: It may help Readers to point out that this algorithm differs from the usual Euclidean algorithm by updating only $a$ from one iteration to the next ($p$ remains constant).